# How to set Latin Spanish to Google cloud Text-To-Speech voice?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I want to set the Latin Spanish language to GC Text-To-Speech voice on Android app. From what I read in the [Google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) for tts the only spanish available is Spanish from spain. Is there any way I can achieve this even if I have to use any other library, framework, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Latin Spanish is not available on google TTS service. You may consider using Microsoft Speech API as it supports Mexican Spanish.

[Microsoft Language and region support for the Speech Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support)

I believe  "Mexican Spanish" or "Latin American Spanish", are the same thing as mentioned by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Spanish)

Comment: The term "Latin Spanish" is problematic. There are MANY varieties of Spanish spoken in Latin America and even within Mexico. So "Mexican Spanish" or "Latin American Spanish" are NOT the same thing. It is a shame google doesn't support TTS for Mexican Spanish as it is the most widely spoken dialect of Spanish in the world.